# How to limit(control) the number of tabs of ngx-bootstrap dynamic tabs-angular 2+

Tags: angular, angular6, angular5, ngx-bootstrap

I am using the dynamic tabs using **ngx-bootstrap**,

**My UI flow:**

*step1*:- Have to use the tree table which contains policy, category and subcategory.

*step2*:- clicking on Policy opens the categories.

*step3*: clicking on category opens the subcategories.

*step4*: clicking on categories opens the ngx-bootstrap dynamic tabs.

**Here is my stackblitz example**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hdw4fh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

**Problem**:-

I have to limit the tabs controls. Which means I have to open the tabs upto 10 (not more than 10). But in this case the tabs opening is going unlimited.

Is there any way to limit the number of tabs??
Can anybody help me??

Comment: In the beginning of `addNewTab` method, check if `this.tabs.length` equals 10. If it is, show some alert or message and return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below code to the beginning of the `addNewTab`:

```
if (this.tabs.length == 10) {
  alert("Max 10 tabs");
  return;
}
```

Updated stackblitz sample:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-homrum?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Instead of browser `alert`, you can use the alert component of `ngx-bootstrap` for better user experience:
https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/alerts